# Unsubscribe from Parse Status SMS

Tags: parse-platform

I'm unable to find a way to unsubscribe from Parse Status SMS messages. I also see a question here which doesn't seem to have been answered.

https://www.parse.com/questions/unsubscribe-from-parse-status-sms

Please let me know how I can unsubscribe. Didn't find anything useful here:
https://status.parse.com/

Comment: You should ask their support. Even if the parse.com folks would prefer to send all of their support requests here, these questions are unfortunately off-topic on Stack Overflow as they are not related to any actual programming problem.

Comment: Thanks Holger! I agree and was a bit hesitant to post the Q here. However, a) they didn't seem to answer pretty much the same question (link in the original question) b) have 2 developer communities - Stack Overflow or google groups as best way to reach them - https://www.parse.com/help  I went for Stack Overflow. I would rather avoid joining their google group if possible as I am not using this service anymore. c) couldn't find a third way to reach out to them (may be will tweet at them). Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just reply STOP to the notification message to unsubscribe.